# Partition a 1D char* into 2D char**

Tags: c, arrays, c-strings

There are a lot of questions about converting a 2D array into a 1D array, but I am attempting just the opposite. I'm trying to partition a string into substrings of constant length and house them in a 2D array. Each row of this 2D matrix should contain a substring of the initial string, and, if each row were to be read in succession and concatenated, the initial string should be reproduced.

I nearly have it working, but for some reason I am losing the first substring (partitions[0] -- length 8*blockSize) of the initial string (bin):

```
int main (void){
    char* bin = "00011101010000100001111101001101000010110000111100000010000111110100111100010011010011100011110000011010";
    int blockSize = 2; // block size in bytes
    int numBlocks = strlen(bin)/(8*blockSize); // number of block to analyze
    char** partitions = (char**)malloc((numBlocks+1)*sizeof(char)); // break text into block
    for(int i = 0; i<numBlocks;++i){
        partitions[i] = (char*)malloc((8*blockSize+1)*sizeof(char));
        memcpy(partitions[i],&bin[8*i*blockSize],8*blockSize);
        partitions[i][8*blockSize] = '\0';
        printf("Printing partitions[%d]: %s\n", i, partitions[i]);
    }
    for(int j=0; j<numBlocks;++j)
        printf("Printing partitions[%d]: %s\n", j,partitions[j]);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
Printing partitions[0]: 0001110101000010
Printing partitions[1]: 0001111101001101
Printing partitions[2]: 0000101100001111
Printing partitions[3]: 0000001000011111
Printing partitions[4]: 0100111100010011
Printing partitions[5]: 0100111000111100
Printing partitions[0]: Hj
Printing partitions[1]: 0001111101001101
Printing partitions[2]: 0000101100001111
Printing partitions[3]: 0000001000011111
Printing partitions[4]: 0100111100010011
Printing partitions[5]: 0100111000111100
```

The construction of partitions in the first for loop is successful. After construction at read out, the string at partitions[0] contains garbage values. Can anyone offer some insight?

Comment: `malloc((numBlocks+1)*sizeof(char))` --> `malloc((numBlocks+1)*sizeof(char*))`

Comment: If the strings are to be fixed length, why use pointer to pointer in the first place? You could have declared a 2D array of fixed size.

Comment: I have to agree with @Lundin here, this code does not need any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Their are a few problems with your code.

- You are allocating `**partitions` incorrectly.

  Instead of:

  ```
  char** partitions = (char**)malloc((numBlocks+1)*sizeof(char)); /* dont need +1, as numblocks is enough space. */
  ```

  You need to allocate space for `char*` pointers, not `char` characters.

  instead, this needs to be:

  ```
  char** partitions = malloc((numBlocks+1)*sizeof(char*));
  ```
- Also read [Why not to cast result of malloc()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), as it is not needed in C.
- `malloc()` needs to be checked everytime, as it can return `NULL` when unsuccessful.
- Once finished with the space allocated, it is always good to  [`free()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_free.htm) memory previously requested by `malloc()`. It is important to do this at some point in the program.

Here is some code which shows this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BLOCKSIZE 2
#define BLOCK_MULTIPLIER 8

int main(void) {
    const char *bin = "00011101010000100001111101001101000010110000111100000010000111110100111100010011010011100011110000011010";
    const size_t blocksize = BLOCKSIZE;
    const size_t multiplier = BLOCK_MULTIPLIER;
    const size_t numblocks = strlen(bin)/(multiplier * blocksize);
    const size_t numbytes = multiplier * blocksize;

    char **partitions = malloc(numblocks * sizeof(*partitions));
    if (partitions == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot allocate %zu spaces\n", numblocks);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < numblocks; i++) {
        partitions[i] = malloc(numbytes+1);
        if (partitions[i] == NULL) {
            printf("Cannot allocate %zu bytes for pointer\n", numbytes+1);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        memcpy(partitions[i], &bin[numbytes * i], numbytes);
        partitions[i][numbytes] = '\0';
        printf("Printing partitions[%zu]: %s\n", i, partitions[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
    for(size_t j = 0; j < numblocks; j++) {
        printf("Printing partitions[%zu]: %s\n", j,partitions[j]);
        free(partitions[j]);
        partitions[j] = NULL;
    }

    free(partitions);
    partitions = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Which outputs non-garbage values:

```
Printing partitions[0]: 0001110101000010
Printing partitions[1]: 0001111101001101
Printing partitions[2]: 0000101100001111
Printing partitions[3]: 0000001000011111
Printing partitions[4]: 0100111100010011
Printing partitions[5]: 0100111000111100

Printing partitions[0]: 0001110101000010
Printing partitions[1]: 0001111101001101
Printing partitions[2]: 0000101100001111
Printing partitions[3]: 0000001000011111
Printing partitions[4]: 0100111100010011
Printing partitions[5]: 0100111000111100
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int numBlocks = strlen(bin)/(8*blockSize); // number of block to analyze
char** partitions = (char**)malloc((numBlocks+1)*sizeof(char)); // break text into block
for(int i = 0; i<numBlocks;++i){
    partitions[i] = (char*)malloc((8*blockSize+1)*sizeof(char));
    memcpy(partitions[i],&bin[8*i*blockSize],8*blockSize);
    partitions[i][8*blockSize] = '\0';
    printf("Printing partitions[%d]: %s\n", i, partitions[i]);
}
```

This all looks suspicious to me; it's far too complex for the task, making it a prime suspect for errors.

1. For reasons explained in answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc), `void *` pointers which are returned by `malloc` and other functions *shouldn't* be casted.
2. There's no need to multiply by 1 (`sizeof (char)` is **always** 1 in C). In fact, in your first call to `malloc` you should be multiplying by `sizeof (char *)` (or better yet, `sizeof *partitions`, as in the example below), since that's the size of the type of element that `partitions` points at.
3. `malloc` might return `NULL`, resulting in undefined behaviour when you attempt to assign into the location it points at.
4. Anything else (i.e. everything that isn't `NULL`) that `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc` returns will need to be `free`d when no longer in use, or else tools such as [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) (a leak detection program, useful for people who habitually forget to `free` allocated objects and thus cause memory leaks) will report false positives and lose part of their usefulness.
5. `numBlocks`, `i`, or anything else that's for counting elements of an array, should be declared as a `size_t` to follow standard convention (e.g. check the [strlen manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strlen.html), synopsis section to see how `strlen` is declared, noting the type of the return value is `size_t`). Negative values caused by overflows here will obviously cause the program to misbehave.
6. I gather you've yet to think about any excess beyond the last group of 8 characters... This shouldn't be difficult to incorporate.

I suggest using a single allocation, such as:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BLOCK_SIZE 8

int main(void) {
    char const *bin = "00011101010000100001111101001101000010110000111100000010000111110100111100010011010011100011110000011010";
    size_t bin_length = strlen(bin),
           block_count = (bin_length / BLOCK_SIZE)
                       + (bin_length % BLOCK_SIZE > 0); // excess as per point 6 above
    char (*block)[BLOCK_SIZE + 1] = malloc(block_count * sizeof *block);
    if (!block) { exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
    for (size_t x = 0; x < block_count; x++) {
        snprintf(block[x], BLOCK_SIZE + 1, "%s", bin + x * BLOCK_SIZE);
        printf("Printing partitions[%zu]: %s\n", x, block[x]);
    }
    for (size_t x = 0; x < block_count; x++) {
        printf("Printing partitions[%zu]: %s\n", x, block[x]);
    }
    free(block);
    exit(0);
}
```